# Formatting an Excel file with XlsxWriter - Locale settings appear not to be applied to the output file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, formatting, xlsxwriter

I've been trying, for a while now to solve this formatting problem for work, but to no avail.

I'll try to be brief and concise: I am writing a Python script as part of an automation job. The script is expected to work with two .csv file as input, downloaded from the client's Database. The .csv files are obtained elswhere through an automation software. After that, I have basically read the main .csv (csv_dataframe) as a DataFrame with headers, and the other one (csv_depara_espec) with no headers; then I edited the main csv so I could alter the columns positions; then filled a column with translated information from the secondary csv. Up to this point, all was done using Pandas. Afterwards, I've created an excel_dataframe using xlsxwriter as engine, then I've created some formatting objects, and then I've applied them to specific columns within the excel_dataframe.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from typing import Self
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.excel
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import time
import xlsxwriter

template_excel_file = r"C:\CriarTabelaOpme\Modelo Material Alto Custo - Intranet.xlsx"
depara_nome_espec_file = r"C:\CriarTabelaOpme\Especialidade_Dicionario.csv"

report_csv_file = r"C:\CriarTabelaOpme\ReportServiceIntranet.csv"

csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(report_csv_file, sep = ',', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine = 'python', index_col = None, names = ['TIPO', 'CODIGO', 'PTU', 
'DESCRICAO', 'FORNECEDOR', 'VALOR', 'COD_PRINCP_ATIVO', 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO', 'ANVISA', 'VALIDADE_RMS', 'FABRICANTE', 'DT_ATUALIZACAO', 'PTU_LIMITE', 'COD_ESP', 'NOME_ESPEC', 'REFERENCIA', 'OBSERVACAO'])
csv_dataframe.insert(16, "", "")

csv_depara_espec = pd.read_csv(depara_nome_espec_file, sep = ',', header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine = 'python')
#print(csv_depara_espec)

csv_dataframe = csv_dataframe.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,14,15]]
#print(csv_dataframe)

for row in range(len(csv_dataframe)):

    cod_esp_row = (csv_dataframe.iloc[row, 13])
    csv_dataframe.iloc[row,14] = csv_depara_espec.iloc[cod_esp_row, 1]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(template_excel_file, engine = 'xlsxwriter', date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY')

excel_dataframe = csv_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Material Alto Custo', index = False, header = ['TIPO', 'CODIGO', 'PTU', 
'DESCRICAO', 'FORNECEDOR', 'VALOR', 'COD_PRINCP_ATIVO', 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO', 'ANVISA', 'VALIDADE_RMS', 'FABRICANTE', 'DT_ATUALIZACAO', 
'PTU_LIMITE', 'COD_ESP', 'NOME_ESPEC', 'REFERENCIA', 'OBSERVACAO'])

(max_row, max_col) = csv_dataframe.shape

workbook = writer.book 
worksheet = writer.sheets['Material Alto Custo']

header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold' : True, 
'font' : 'Arial', 
'size' : 10})

font_and_size = workbook.add_format({'font' : 'Arial', 'size' : 10}) 
column_valor_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '[$R$-pt-BR] #.##0,00'}) 
column_date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : 'dd/mm/yyyy'}) 
column_left_zeroes_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : '00000000'})

worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_format)

worksheet.set_column(0,max_col, 20.0, font_and_size)

worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 20.0, column_left_zeroes_format)
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 20.0, column_left_zeroes_format)

worksheet.set_column(5, 5, 20.0, column_valor_format)

worksheet.set_column(9, 9, 20.0, column_date_format)
worksheet.set_column(11, 11, 20.0, column_date_format)
worksheet.set_column(12, 12, 20.0, column_date_format)

for i, j in enumerate(list(csv_dataframe.columns)):
    worksheet.write(0, i, j, header_format)

#Fechar planilha
writer.close()
```

All in all, formatting the header, every colmun with font and size, and columns B and C (indexes 1 and 2) with a zero mask to the left of the number works perfectly, but the formatting of values (currency, Brazilian Real) and dates do not.

This is the resulting formatting after code excecution:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

And this is the expected result:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I've obtained the expected results by manually double clicking each cell in every row and then pressing enter. First four rows where manually altered to demonstrate the desired effects. Altered columns are F, J, M and M.

I reckon this must be due to locale formatting of Excel files (Brazilian Portuguese opposed to United States English, which is the format region on the VM I use at work). Is there anything to be done regarding this problem?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Dates and numbers in Excel have no format, they're both binary numeric values AND THAT'S A GOOD THING - it means formulas and calculations don't change if the locale changes. How they're displayed depends on the *end user's locale*, unless a custom cell style is used. The way the built-in styles are displayed depends on the end user's locale

Comment: BTW the answer comes from the author of XlsxWriter. It does add a new custom format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'll study the xlsxwriter doc in further detail. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

For the question in the title on the locale, you will need to use the US style thousands and decimal point values "," and "." instead of the locale variant. In this case `'[$R$-pt-BR] #,##0.00'` instead of `'[$R$-pt-BR] #.##0,00'`. This is explained in more detail in the [Number Formats in different locales](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-formats-in-different-locales) section of the XlsxWriter docs.

Secondly, the currency/number values are actually strings since the data was read from CSV. In your image you will notice the green triangles in the Excel cells indicating that there are numbers stored as strings. Excel can't/doesn't apply number formats to strings so you will need to convert those columns to float for the number format to take effect.

Also, the date and datetime formats are set by Pandas for each cell and can't be overridden by a column format. You will need to set the date format in the `ExcelWriter()` APIs.

Here is a smaller example that makes these changes:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some datetime data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'valididad': [datetime(2023, 1, 1, 11, 30, 55),
                                 datetime(2023, 1, 2, 1,  20, 33),
                                 datetime(2023, 1, 3, 11, 10, 21),
                                 datetime(2023, 1, 4, 16, 45, 35),
                                 datetime(2023, 1, 5, 12, 10, 15)],
                   'valor':    ['53.4',
                                '723.19',
                                '1723.19',
                                '2723.19',
                                '1000000'],
                   })


# Convert numbers as strings to floats.
df['valor'] = df['valor'].astype(float)

# Also set the default datetime and date formats.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_test.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        date_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
                        datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy')


# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Set the currency format.
valor_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '[$R$-pt-BR] #,##0.00'})
worksheet.set_column(1, 2, 16, valor_format)


# Set the column width to make the dates clearer.
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 16)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Which should give the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Hey, jmcnamara. Thank you for your reply!

As it happens, your solution works partially in this case. The local currency appears correct, but I still have to double click the cell and press ENTER afterwards:
R$ 54,40  --> double click + enter
R$ 723,19  --> double click + enter
723,19 --> this value is as appears at the cell when the workbook is opened.

Also, any clues about the date formatting?

The values that appear to me when I first open the spreadsheet are on format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', but I wanted the values to be shown as 'dd/MM/yyyy' only.

Many thanks!

Comment: @LeonardoLeipnitz, I missed the part of the question about the dates. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the update! I'll test your corrections right away!

Comment: I've tested the corrections you told me, and converting the VALOR column data type from object to float did the trick:
csv_dataframe["VALOR"] = csv_dataframe["VALOR"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(",", "")).astype('float').

However, changing date_format and datetime_format within the ExcelWriter() API did not solve the issue. Below is the code snippet:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(template_excel_file, engine = 'xlsxwriter', date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy', datetime_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy')

Any thoughts about the above writer object? Many thanks!

Comment: It is probably the same issue as the currency values. That the dates are strings and not actual date time objects. You can test this in excel by changing the format to General. If it doesn’t change to a number then it is a string. You will need to convert them to dates (using `to_datetime()` or similar) for the formatting to work.

Comment: That was the issue, exactly. Solved using to_datetime() as you said:
csv_dataframe["VALIDADE_RMS"] = pd.to_datetime(csv_dataframe["VALIDADE_RMS"])
csv_dataframe["DT_ATUALIZACAO"] = pd.to_datetime(csv_dataframe["DT_ATUALIZACAO"])
csv_dataframe["PTU_LIMITE"] = pd.to_datetime(csv_dataframe["PTU_LIMITE"])

Many thanks!