# Cannot set header and specific column (type date) formatting - XlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-science, xlsxwriter

I've been trying to edit a dataframe into a formated Excel spreadsheet for work, and though most issues were solved elsewhere ([Formatting an Excel file with XlsxWriter - Locale settings appear not to be applied to the output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75139795/formatting-an-excel-file-with-xlsxwriter-locale-settings-appear-not-to-be-appl)) some remained.

The problem now is with the header and border formatting passed to date columns:
[[image: training data output]]

I expected to have borders on all sides of each cell, but colmuns J, L and M, which receive information in datetime type, present border formatting issues (no borders actually). Also, there is an extra colmun (R) which is formated.
Keep in mind that columns B, C and F were also formated using xlsxwriter and have no border formatting problems.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
# Importar bibliotecas
import os
from typing import Self
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel
import pandas.io.excel
import numpy as np
import time
import xlsxwriter

template_excel_file = r"C:\CriarTabelaOpme\Modelo Material Alto Custo - Intranet.xlsx"
depara_nome_espec_file = r"C:\CriarTabelaOpme\Especialidade_Dicionario.csv"

report_csv_file = r"C:\CriarTabelaOpme\ReportServiceIntranet.csv"

csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(report_csv_file, sep = ',', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine = 'python', index_col = None, names = ['TIPO', 'CODIGO', 'PTU', 
'DESCRICAO', 'FORNECEDOR', 'VALOR', 'COD_PRINCP_ATIVO', 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO', 'ANVISA', 'VALIDADE_RMS', 'FABRICANTE', 'DT_ATUALIZACAO', 'PTU_LIMITE', 'COD_ESP', 'NOME_ESPEC', 'REFERENCIA', 'OBSERVACAO'])
csv_dataframe.insert(16, "", "")

csv_dataframe["VALOR"] = csv_dataframe["VALOR"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(",", "")).astype('float')

csv_dataframe["VALIDADE_RMS"] = pd.to_datetime(csv_dataframe["VALIDADE_RMS"])
csv_dataframe["DT_ATUALIZACAO"] = pd.to_datetime(csv_dataframe["DT_ATUALIZACAO"])
csv_dataframe["PTU_LIMITE"] = pd.to_datetime(csv_dataframe["PTU_LIMITE"])

#print(csv_dataframe.dtypes)

csv_depara_espec = pd.read_csv(depara_nome_espec_file, sep = ',', header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine = 'python')
#print(csv_depara_espec)

csv_dataframe = csv_dataframe.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,14,15]]
#print(csv_dataframe)

dict = {'TIPO' : 'TIPO', 'CODIGO' : 'CODIGO', 'PTU': 'PTU', 
'DESCRICAO' : 'DESCRICAO', 'FORNECEDOR' : 'FORNECEDOR', 'VALOR' : 'VALOR', 'COD_PRINCP_ATIVO' : 'COD_PRINCP_ATIVO',
 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO' : 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO', 'ANVISA' : 'ANVISA', 'VALIDADE_RMS' : 'VALIDADE_RMS', 'FABRICANTE' : 'FABRICANTE',
  'DT_ATUALIZACAO' : 'DT_ATUALIZACAO', 'PTU_LIMITE' : 'PTU_LIMITE', 'COD_ESP' : 'COD_ESP', '' : 'NOME_ESPEC', 
  'NOME_ESPEC' : 'REFERENCIA', 'REFERENCIA' : 'OBSERVACAO'}
csv_dataframe.rename(columns = dict, inplace = True)


for row in range(len(csv_dataframe)):

    cod_esp_row = (csv_dataframe.iloc[row, 13])
    csv_dataframe.iloc[row,14] = csv_depara_espec.iloc[cod_esp_row, 1]

pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(template_excel_file, engine = 'xlsxwriter', date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy', datetime_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy')

excel_dataframe = csv_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Material Alto Custo', index = False, header = ['TIPO', 'CODIGO', 'PTU', 
'DESCRICAO', 'FORNECEDOR', 'VALOR', 'COD_PRINCP_ATIVO', 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO', 'ANVISA', 'VALIDADE_RMS', 'FABRICANTE', 'DT_ATUALIZACAO', 
'PTU_LIMITE', 'COD_ESP', 'NOME_ESPEC', 'REFERENCIA', 'OBSERVACAO'])

(max_row, max_col) = csv_dataframe.shape

workbook = writer.book 
worksheet = writer.sheets['Material Alto Custo']

header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold' : True, 
'font' : 'Arial', 
'size' : 10,
'border' : 1})

font_size_and_border = workbook.add_format({'font' : 'Arial', 'size' : 10, 'border' : 1})
column_valor_format_and_border = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '[$R$-pt-BR] #,##0.00','font' : 'Arial', 'size' : 10,  'border' : 1})
column_date_format_and_border = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : 'dd/mm/yyyy','font' : 'Arial', 'size' : 10,  'border' : 1})
column_left_zeroes_format_and_border = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : '00000000','font' : 'Arial', 'size' : 10,  'border' : 1})

worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_format)

worksheet.set_column(0,max_col, 20.0, font_size_and_border)

worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 20.0, column_left_zeroes_format_and_border)
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 20.0, column_left_zeroes_format_and_border)

worksheet.set_column(5, 5, 20.0, column_valor_format_and_border)

worksheet.set_column(9, 9, 20.0, column_date_format_and_border)
worksheet.set_column(11, 11, 20.0, column_date_format_and_border)
worksheet.set_column(12, 12, 20.0, column_date_format_and_border)

worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_format)

writer.close()
```

I've been trying to spot the error, but I have failed. Could someone help me out?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: The reason this happens is that Pandas adds a cell format to each cell that contains a date since that is a minimum requirement for formatting a number into a date. However, since the cell already has a format it overrides/ignores the column format. There isn't an easy way around this, as far as I know, apart from iterating over the date values in the dataframe and overwriting the datetime cells via the xlsxwriter worksheet instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @jmcnamara! Must I use worksheet.write()? I have tried using set_row(), but it does not work.

Any clues regarding the header formatting issue? Many thanks!

Comment: EDIT: solved the header issue:
for col_num, value in enumerate(csv_dataframe.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

The code above formatted the header correctly.

Comment: I have tried the following for loop using the worksheet instance, but it did not work:
row_num = 0
for col_num, value in enumerate(csv_dataframe['VALIDADE_RMS']):
    row_idx = 1
    if (row_idx > 0):
        for row_num, value in enumerate(csv_dataframe, start = 1):
            row_num = row_idx
            if row_num > 1:
                worksheet.write(row_num, 9, value, column_date_format_and_border)
    row_idx += 1

The above code was supposed to overwrite both values and formatting on one of the date columns.
@jmcnamara, any clues? Many thanks!